# Taking too long to initialize h2o in r

Tags: r, h2o

I'm trying to initialize `h2o` on my windows machine using `h2o.init()`. It was working fine till yesterday, but today it's taking too long to initialize and is giving warning messages:

```
h2o.init()
 Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         5 days 23 hours 
    H2O cluster timezone:       America/New_York 
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
    H2O cluster version:        3.18.0.11 
    H2O cluster version age:    19 days  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_tfx859 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   0.46 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
    H2O cluster healthy:        FALSE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    H2O API Extensions:         Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4 
    R Version:                  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
```

> Warning in .h2o.__checkConnectionHealth() :
>     H2O cluster node 1.0.0.1:5 is behaving slowly and should be inspected manually
>   Warning in .h2o.__checkConnectionHealth() :
>     Check H2O cluster status here: http://localhost:5/3/Cloud?skip_ticks=true

How do I solve this problem?

Also, it's throwing errors after making a connection to `h2o` when I'm trying to convert a data frame to `h2o` object using `test.h2o <- as.h2o(test)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that one of your nodes is behaving slowly (something's gone wrong on that machine to have it behave slowly, not an H2O issue).  My recommendation is to shut down the H2O cluster using `h2o.shutdown()`, then restart all your nodes, and then re-start the H2O cluster.  That should fix it.

Comment: I had tried `h2o.shutdown` to restart the cluster. It fixed the problem, forgot to update it here. Before running into this issue I ran `automl` for more than 12 hours. Do you think it could have something to do with making the cluster slow?

Comment: That might have something to do with it -- the H2O cluster might have run out of memory because it was storing so many models, so if you can, give it more memory.  If you download H2O 3.20.0.1 from h2o.ai/download, you can use the new `keep_cross_validation_models` option in AutoML which you can set to `FALSE`.  This will throw away CV models, which should free up additional memory.

Comment: When I get this error it has usually meant I've used up too much memory (made too many models). At that point it is usually too late to recover gracefully, so I have to kill it and re-start. Be aware that you can pass an arg to h2o.init(), e.g. `max_mem_size="4G"`, to give it more memory. If the machine is not doing anything else, you should be able to safely allocate all but 1G of your system memory to H2O.

Answer (score 1):

Notice this:

> H2O cluster total memory:   0.46 GB

This is far too little memory for H2O to run.  I recommend nothing less than 5 GB.